# Expectation value of absolute value of difference of two random variables

Tags: random-variables, expectation, absolute-value

I do not really know how to prove the following statement:

> If $E(|X-Y|)=0$  then $P(X=Y)=1$.

The main problem is how to handle the absolute value $|X-Y|$. 
If I say that $|X-Y| \geq 0$ it follows that $E(X)=E(Y)$ which is 
also the result for $|X-Y|<0$. But then the expectation values are equal
and you can show that $P(X=Y)=1$ is not true for all $X,Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Simple proof by contradiction:

Assume that $P(X=Y)<1$, then there has to exists $x',y'$ such that $x'\neq y'$ and $P(X=x'\wedge Y=y')>0$.

But then if we look at the random variable $Z=|X-Y|$, we get that
$$E(Z)=\sum_{x,y}P(X=x\wedge Y=y)\cdot|x-y|$$
$$=P(X=x'\wedge Y=y')\cdot|x'-y'|+\sum_{x,y\neq(x',y')}P(X=x\wedge Y=y)\cdot|x-y|$$

Since $$P(X=x'\wedge Y=y')\cdot|x'-y'|$$ is strictly positive and

$$\sum_{x,y\neq(x',y')}P(X=x\wedge Y=y)\cdot|x-y|$$
Is non-negative, it follows that $E(Z)>0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that already looks very good. But what about continuous random variables?

Comment: @user3523615 - same proof. Replace $P(X=x'\wedge Y=y')>0$ by $f_{X,Y}(x',y')>0$.

Comment: Of course, I checked it out, thank you. Theoretically, you do not have to use a contradiction to prove it, do you? I tried it straightforward, i.e. I began with E(|X-Y|) = 0 and came to the same result.

Comment: @user3523615 - oh course. Every thing you can prove by contradiction can be proved without it (in logic, if we wish to prove $a\vdash b$, it is the same as proving $\neg b\vdash \neg a$), that's just a way of looking at the proof.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
0{}={}\mathbb{E}\left[\ \big| X-Y\big|\ \right]&{}={}&\mathbb{E}\left[\ \big| X-Y\big|\ \bigg| \ X\ne Y\right]P\left(X\ne Y\right){}+{}\mathbb{E}\left[\ \big| X-Y\big|\ \bigg| \ X= Y\right]P\left(X= Y\right)\newline
&&\newline
&{}={}&\mathbb{E}\left[\ \big| X-Y\big|\ \bigg| \ X\ne Y\right]P\left(X\ne Y\right)\,.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Therefore,

> $$
> \mathbb{E}\left[\ \big| X-Y\big|\ \bigg| \ X\ne Y\right]\ne0\implies P\left(X\ne Y\right)=0\implies P\left(X= Y\right)=1\,.
> $$